# PowerShell search for files from CSV and output dir if found

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to piece together a PowerShell script from what I've read on here to search a CSV list of filenames in a directory and subdirectories and then if found output the directory path with the filename out into a CSV, or if it is not found just the filename with not found next to it.

Below is what I've done so far, it works to an extent however it is not 'finding' the files, it just reports them all not found even though the files are there to be found in my test folder.

```
Import-Csv -Path files.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse $_.filename
    if ($_.filename -eq $_.Name) {
        $_.path = $_.FullName
    } else {
        $_.path = "NOT FOUND"
    }
    $_
} | Select-Object filename,path | Export-Csv -Path output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: your 2nd line doesn't store anything. [*grin*] then your 3rdl line tries to compare two properties OF THE SAME OBJECT. [*grin*] again ... ///// instead of using the pipeline, try using a standard loop such as `foreach` [not the `ForEach-Object` pipeline cmdlet]. that will let you clearly assign things to independent $Vars that can be cleanly, clearly, _individually_ dealt with.

Comment: you are most welcome ... and good luck! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

What if the file is found in more than one folder?

- storing the found folder(s), creating a [PSCustomObject] and assigning output to variable `$Result`
- Incorporating [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001484/powershell-search-for-files-from-csv-and-output-dir-if-found#comment94840027_54001484)s helpful hint

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\01\02\SO_54001484.ps1
$Result = ForEach ($file in (Import-Csv -Path files.csv)){
    $FoundInFolders = (Get-ChildItem $file.filename -File -Recurse ).FullName
    if ($FoundInFolders.Count -eq 0) {
        $FoundInFolders = "NOT FOUND"
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        filename = $file.filename
        path = $FoundInFolders -join ', '
    }
}

$Result #| Export-Csv -Path output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\01\02\SO_54001484.ps1

filename path
-------- ----
test.cmd NOT FOUND
test.csv Q:\Test\2018\03\20\1\test.csv, Q:\Test\2018\03\20\2\test.csv, Q:\Test\2018\03\20\3\test.csv
test.ps1 Q:\Test\2018\03\31\test.ps1
blabla   NOT FOUND
```